# jQuery animation with deferred pipes?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use pipes for my animate commands in a jQuery script.  I have 18 animate functions that I want to run sequentially, then I need the CSS position to reset so I can run the animation again.

**NB :  I have updated this code to chain the commands as suggested, new code is.....**

```
$.Deferred(function(dfr) {
dfr.pipe(function() {
$(".block1").delay(500).fadeIn().animate({"left": "+=600px"}, 2500, "linear") .animate({left: '+=10', bottom: '+=10'}, 100, "linear").animate({"left": "+=27px"}, 100, "linear").animate({left: '+=10', bottom: '-=10'}, 100, "linear").animate({"left": "+=25px"}, 100, "linear").fadeOut().css('background', 'red'); 
$(".block2").delay(500).fadeIn().animate({"left": "+=692px"}, 2870, "linear").fadeOut(); 
$(".block3").delay(4010).fadeIn().animate({"left": "+=29px"}, 250, "linear").fadeOut(); 
$(".block4").delay(4010).fadeIn().animate({"left": "+=10px"}, 250, "linear").animate({bottom: '+=15'}, 100, "linear").fadeOut();
}).
pipe(function() {
$(".block1").css('left', '0px');
}).
pipe(function() {
$(".block1").delay(500).fadeIn(); 
});
}).resolve();
```

I have used the example at http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/09/jquery-deferred-objects-and-sequential.html for this.  It wont work for me.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions passed to the pipe method should ["return another observable object"](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/). In this case you can simply pass back the animation.

e.g.:

```
$.Deferred(function (dfr){
    dfr.pipe(function (){
        return $(".block1").delay(500).fadeIn(); 
    });
}).resolve();
```

Answer (score 1):

While this won't solve your issue, chain those commands.  It'll be more efficient, rather than having to run through the dom with each call.

```
$(".block1").delay(500).fadeIn()
    .animate({"left": "+=600px"}, 2500, "linear")
    .animate({left: '+=10', bottom: '+=10'}, 100, "linear");
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, ive tried to implement chaining using the code at http://pastebin.com/YvDsp0YH but its not working.  Can you see what im doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I have managed to chain those commands,  Ive updated the code above.  The CSS is still being triggered at the same time though :(