# jquery animation - when do they finish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two jquery animations one by other:

```
        books.animate({ left: left1 }, {
            duration: this.slideDuration,
            easing: this.easing,
            complete: complete
        });

        laptops.animate({ left: left2 }, {
            duration: this.slideDuration,
            easing: this.easing,
            complete: complete
        });
```

I want the animations to run simultanusly so I use `{queue: false}`:

```
books.animate({ left: left1 }, {
            duration: this.slideDuration,
            easing: this.easing,
                            queue: false,
            complete: complete
        });

        laptops.animate({ left: left2 }, {
            duration: this.slideDuration,
            easing: this.easing,
                            queue: false,
            complete: complete
        });
```

But now the completed callback called twice! How can I know exactly when does the both animations are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery deferred methods try

```
$.when( 
    books.animate({ left: left1 }, {
        duration: this.slideDuration,
        easing: this.easing
    }),
    laptops.animate({ left: left2 }, {
        duration: this.slideDuration,
        easing: this.easing
  })
).done( function( ) {

    alert("done!");

});
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VXpp3/33/)

Comment: I can't see how this would work? How can jQuery understand when the animation inside the anonymous functions is finished?

Comment: @NULL you are absolutely right. Thank you for that. I have corrected my code.

Comment: @NULL: It appears animate returns deferred object which can be used with when. I works great.

Answer (score 1):

Why not remove the `complete` handler from one of the animations?

From the extract of code that you've posted, it looks as though you're using the same duration and easing methods on both animations. Therefore it's inherently true that they will complete at the same time, so long as they're being called at the same time...

Comment: In this case I can really count on the duration, but if tommorrow someone will change the duration, the  code will not work properly. Lets assume there are two ajax calls and we need to know when do they done.

Answer (score 1):

this may sounds like something complicated, but why not `Deferred Objects` ?

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

you may investigate more here
[jQuery animation with deferred pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639213/jquery-animation-with-deferred-pipes)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://darcyclarke.me/development/using-jquery-deferreds-with-animations/:

```
books.animate({ left: left1 }, {
    duration: this.slideDuration,
    easing: this.easing,
    queue: false
});

laptops.animate({ left: left2 }, {
    duration: this.slideDuration,
    easing: this.easing,
    queue: false
});

$.when(books, laptops).done(complete);
```